# Why is "Export Template" button not clickable

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-resource-group

I have a question regarding Resource Group on Microsoft Azure.
I'd like to copy a resource group so was trying to create ARM template via the "Export template"
However, as you can see in the image, the export button was not clickable.
I checked the role in the resource group and confirmed I have an "Owner" role.
Am I missing something? ANy comments would be appreciated
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yfkr8.png)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the export button to become active you have to select the resources that you want to include in the template.